# How to print the contents of an array line by line in a text file?

Tags: python, procedure

I am trying to document the name of employees who have been short listed as successful applicants for a job in a text file with the name of each person in a separate line on the text file, there is a counter index variable that is checked inside the loop to tell the program on when to break a line and when not to break a line. Except that the code I have prints two names on the first line, below is my logic. Help me tell this program to print a single name on each line

```
applicants = ["Timothy", "David", "Mary", "Drew", "Titus", "Samuel","Avery"]
# sort the names of the applicants
applicants.sort()
#initialize the index variable
index = 0
#write the name of each applicant to the file
for el in applicants:  # write the name of the worker to the text file
    if index == 0:  # this is the first line no need for a line break
        file.write(el)
        # increment the index for later iterations
        index += 1
    elif index == len(names)-1:#  this is the last line no need for a line break
        file.write(el)
        index += 1
    else:  # these are the middle lines and it is essential to break a line
        file.write(el+"\n")
        index += 1
```

Comment: Can you reconcile the statements "*the code I have prints two names on the first line*" from your question and `# this is the first line no need for a line break` from your code? They are at odds with each other.

Comment: @esqew, its just a comment and its supposed to tell you that we are aware index is at zero and we are in the first iteration of the first element of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug/issue was in your logic specifically in your else block.
for **David** your index is `1` so it will go into `else` block and in `else` block you are writing line as `el+"\n"` so `David` is being added on same line as `Avery` and then new line is added. I hope it cleared your doubt. So if in `else` block you can do `file.write("\n"+el)` and in `elif` too.

Another way can be:-

```py
with open("Fiddle.txt","w") as file:
    file.writelines("\n".join(applicants)) # will join elements of list with "\n"
```

will print names on new lines.

Comment: But it should be 0 because the script has not yet reached the part where the index is incremented

Comment: Nah in your given example 1st is Avery write which is printed on 1st line then index becomes 1 and as index is 1 it will go into else block and there 2nd element is written but you are writing element and then adding new line so that is the reason 2nd element is on same line as first.

Comment: gotcha, I can't believe I never saw that

Comment: Glad it cleared your doubt. You can mark anyone of the answer as answer which you find appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use more pythonic approach to achieve desired output.

```py
file.writelines('\n'.join(applicants))
```

Comment: This is very dynamic  thus efficient as it let's me write less code with the same output

Answer (score 1):

you should simply print your line break at the start of each line instead of the end. That way you do not need to account for the last line too !
You also can get rid of the incrementing of the index.

```py
for el in applicants:  # write the name of the worker to the text file
    if index == 0:  # this is the first line no need for a line break
        file.write(el)
        # increment the index for later iterations
        index += 1
    else:  # these are the middle lines and it is essential to break a line
        file.write("\n"+el)
```

Comment: I do not understand how this worked but it did and Thank You.

Comment: line breaks can be at the end or the start - it doesn't change anything since they define lines in your file. It means you can place them when you want to. Check out the other answers too, because they are easier ways to write lines. You probably shouldn't be minding the last line break though, except for specific situations.

Comment: I need to because I might need to call `readlines` from another script on the same file and it will read even the empty line

Answer (score 0):

```
applicants = ["Timothy", "David", "Mary", "Drew", "Titus", "Samuel","Avery"]
# sort the names of the applicants
applicants.sort()

with open("sample.txt", "w+") as f:
    for name in applicants:
        f.write(str(name) + "\n")
```

Comment: I do not need a line break in the last line though